# Bad idea to load several User Controls application wide in the web.config in an ASP.NET Webforms Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, web-config

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application that uses 20+ user controls.

Currently I am loading all of them in the application's Web.config file like this:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="custom" src="~/UserControls/Control1.ascx" tagName="Control1" />
    <add tagPrefix="custom" src="~/UserControls/Control2.ascx" tagName="Control2" />
    ......... and 18 more...
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Most of these UserControls are only used on one to two pages throughout the entire application. Is it smarter to load them at the page level in this case? Can someone explain what happens when a user control is registered in a webforms app, maybe if I knew this it would answer the question. I am hoping it doesn't add a huge ViewState on every single page.

I am just looking to optimize my app in anyway possible. So I would like to know if there is any benefit to loading the controls per page rather than application wide when you have 20+ controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am hoping it doesn't add a huge ViewState on every single page.

No, that certainly not.

So what does happen? Those keys are just send to the render engine that tries to compile markup into C# code. That means that a long list of controls will take a little more time to find an item, but in the end it doesn't really matter. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know! Thank you. I will mark correct as soon as it lets me.